# Paste copied text as "TEXT" format in Excel without apostrophe

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cell-format

I have a function in a web app that generates a list of values that can be pasted into Excel.  This code is in javascript.  Each line is generated with the following line of code:

```
exportList += `\n${trc}\t${tacc}\t${tamt}`;
```

For those not sure of the above code:

- `${trc}`, `${tacc}`, and `${tamt}` are variables.
  = `\n` is a new line character that ensures a new row is used for the three cells this chart uses.
- `\t` is a horizontal tabulation which ensures each value is entered into a separate cell on the same row.

The code above, with the remaining code I didn't display will result in the following:
(Looks a bit messy, but the tabs ARE there).

```
RC  Account Number  Amount
4837    2432586567856785    5678
4837    2436245385375675    6345
```

The problem is that for the middle variable, `tacc`, uses a long number that converts to scientific notation.  For the number "2432586567856785", it would display as "2.43259E+15" in the cell.

Right clicking yields only the ability to paste the text in (other times I can paste text without formatting changes so I don't know why).

Now I know in Excel, typing `'` in front of your string will result in it auto-formatting as text.  I tried doing that for the generated text:

```
RC  Account Number  Amount
4837    '2432586567856785   5678
4837    '2436245385375675   6345
```

However, while the account number now only displays as text, without further editing, the apostrophe shows up.  I don't want that.

**Without changing default options, how can I structure the string to force excel to accept the long account number as a text string, without any other characters showing?**

EDIT: After initially finding nothing, I found a [duplicate of this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/285670/paste-to-excel-from-clipboard-plain-text-can-i-make-certain-cells-to-be-form).  Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question, as that involves additional steps.  As the code that I've written is expressly intended to *remove* steps, I still want to know if there's a workaround, where pasting the (long) numerical data remains as text instead of a number with scientific notation...

Comment: Maybe you can use Power Query to format cells: https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/steps-to-format-columns-using-power-query/

Comment: Nah, the issue is that with a single click, I need the text that's copied to the clipboard to just "work", being pasted into a brand new excel document, or at the very least pasted into a document with the most common default cell formatting (general, I've found).  The less need to tinker with excel directly, the better.  My answer below works perfectly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Excel, there is a formula to convert a given value to text:

```
=TEXT(<number value>,"#")
```

So, for the given three numbers, `4320  9876523615862870    10000`, you will need to use the following sequence:

```
=TEXT(4320,"#") =TEXT(9876523615862870,"#") =TEXT(10000,"#")
```

This reliably results in three cells, left to right, with the three numbers.

The original line of code would need to be modified as follows:

```
exportList += `\n=TEXT(${trc},"#")\t=TEXT(${tacc},"#")\t=TEXT(${tamt},"#")`;
```

**There is a quirk with this!**  When pasting into Excel, it seems to need to be pasted into cells formatted a "General", or whatever is the default.  If you paste into a cell formatted already as text, you'll just get the formula written out, which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will not solve the problem.

The "long number" is 16 digits long. Excel will import it as a number if the import is performed via Paste. Excel can only maintain 15 significant digits in a number so it will chop off the last digit and replace it with a zero. Permanently.

That's IT and that's THAT for this kind of importing. Excel offers NOTHING else.

Even a VBA OnEvent macro must allow the Paste to complete, then fire, so it cannot intercept the paste so it cannot keep Excel from permanently and nothing can restore it.

To perform the paste, as a Paste operation by the user, you need to make a macro to do something like have a button for these Pastes, select the cell you want it pasted into, then click that button. The macro would read the Windows Clipboard and take the contents, tear them into three sets of contents, and then insert them into the cells they go into based upon the selected cell being the leftmost of the three, say. It can insert the three pieces as a number, a string, then a number. This way the 16 digit "long number" can stay complete.

And accurate.

Or one can stop Pasting and use the `Data|Import` wizard (using `Fixed Width` importing so as to have an opportunity to force Excel to import that "column" as Text) after digging for it buried deep in the Ribbon Menu system, or by using Power Query in some manner.

I understand the lovely program you wrote `IS STAYING` but you can surely modify its output routine to force the "long number" to be placed upon it as text. Excel will honor that and insert the value as a text formatted cell with the full string in it.

The message is that there is no `Easy Way Out` on this. You wrote a program and I applaud that as I have not written a program since 1977and that was not technically anything a modern folk would call a program anyway. The only "real" one I ever wrote was on punch cards and ran on the mainframe West Point had access to. (Still have that three feet of punch cards.) So I'm not a programmer and you are. Good man! You wrote it on the fly it seems without proper complete research into what was required. I feel for ya here. But it's time to fix the problem that makes it useless. A tiny fix and then it can be everything you want it to be. And a god amongst men in your office. Dig your feet in and end up insisting users do long, hard things to use it and force them to use it no matter what and you will be thought quite something else amongst men.

Let them use the accepted answer, lopping off the last character, until something nasty happens with whatever decisions this data helps with and you could even be "quite something else... amongst unemployed men."

(By the way, if you only need 15 digits, modify your program to output only 15  digits and all troubles disappear. Well, until you encounter an oddity with Excel's Pasting in that it depends for exactly how it Pastes upon the currently selected delimiters in its `Data|Import` wizard (in its crippled form `Text To Columns`, those get changed, then begin affecting Pasting of this kind of source data... weird, eh?) and the whole current approach breaks until you remember this paragraph and get the users to fix things (when they aren't really broken, exactly, just used).)

As with most things in Excel, the wonderful thing is that it is ENTIRELY YOUR CHOICE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way is to prepare sheet before pasting - change format of the cells that require that.

Also you can automate that process (of changing cells format) by a Excel script.

Unfortunately the other way is to import csv file through Excel import option, where you can set the data type for each column. But this takes some time, which you want to avoid.

Last option is to make script which will build ready Excel file from given data.

Comment: The problem is that the app is using HTML, JS, and CSS.  It's 100% local, and no permission is given to develop in anything else (it's a fluke I developed this app and it's staying), and no chance for it to be hosted locally, otherwise I'd try to use PHP or something.  It seems like that's the only option left though, pre-formatting.  I was hoping there was a way to like do TEXT="text here" in the tab-delimited values.  Thank you!

Comment: So for Excel specifically, you need to use the formula `=TEXT(<number value>,"#")` to reproduce the number in text.  Not sure if there's any other way but I only need for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. It only displays the formula as text. Instead I added a no-break space (U+00A0) before the number to trick Excel to format the number as text:

```
exportList += `\n ${trc}\t ${tacc}\t ${tamt}`;
```

Depending on your use case this may be an acceptable workaround.